# How to resolve pandas summing rows like strings, instead of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to get sum over the columns by row-wise for my time series data but the sum is weird. I `reset_index` for `date` and just take sum for all columns by rows. Can anyone point me out what's going on with this? Any quick thought? Thanks

**my attempt**:

Here is the [data that I used](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/ce26357dcabea22f8db307e5d8a625ff) and my attempt here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/ce26357dcabea22f8db307e5d8a625ff#file-ads_df-csv")

df_grp = df.groupby(['date', 'retail_item'])['number_of_stores'].sum().unstack().reset_index('date')
df_grp.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df_grp.loc[:,'Total'] = df_grp.sum(axis=1)
```

but `Total` column is weried, it should get correct sum by using above attempt, but output is wrong. I think something wrong. Can anyone one point me out what is going on here?

here is the current output:

[image: current output]

I also tried like this:

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['date', 'retail_item']).agg({'number_of_stores': 'sum'})
df_grpe_pcts = df_grp.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))
df_grp = df_grp.diff() / df_grp.shift()
```

main motivation is first group by data by `retail_item`, then get sum of `number_of_stores` for all `retail_items` for each week, then I want to get percentage and percentage change respect to total sum. How can I make this right? Any quick idea to make this work in pandas? thanks

### Data Sample

```py
Unnamed: 0,date,region,grade,cut,retail_item,number_of_stores,weighted_avg
40,2016-01-01,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"1,980",4.53
41,2016-01-01,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"4,020",3.65
42,2016-01-01,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,940,2.1
88,2016-01-08,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"3,770",4.76
89,2016-01-08,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"7,770",3.88
90,2016-01-08,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"2,000",2.52
134,2016-01-15,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"6,600",4.69
135,2016-01-15,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"5,640",3.89
136,2016-01-15,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"3,000",2.34
181,2016-01-22,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"1,920",4.79
182,2016-01-22,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"8,830",3.43
183,2016-01-22,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"3,060",2.28
228,2016-01-29,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"2,640",4.2
229,2016-01-29,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"4,420",3.71
230,2016-01-29,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"3,060",2.42
277,2016-02-05,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"4,240",4.87
278,2016-02-05,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"9,820",3.65
279,2016-02-05,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"1,620",2.76
325,2016-02-12,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"4,550",4.88
326,2016-02-12,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"3,540",4.11
327,2016-02-12,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"1,450",2.77
371,2016-02-19,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"3,110",4.84
372,2016-02-19,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"6,270",3.78
373,2016-02-19,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"3,250",2.41
419,2016-02-26,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"3,040",5.04
420,2016-02-26,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"6,420",3.74
421,2016-02-26,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"2,100",2.64
467,2016-03-04,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE,"3,440",4.74
468,2016-03-04,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 80-89%,"6,040",3.58
469,2016-03-04,NATIONAL,SUMMARY,GRND BEEF,GROUND BEEF 70-79%,"2,350",2.55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As you can see in the image `Total` is summing strings together.
- The columns are not correctly parsed as `float` type, because of the `,`.
- The correct way to parse the data, is by using the `thousands` parameter when reading the data with `pandas.read_csv`.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/ce26357dcabea22f8db307e5d8a625ff/raw/1fee3176f5364d0d08b8f97bae781e16c47cea3d/ads_df.csv'

# specify the thousand parameter when reading the data in
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['date'], thousands=',')

# drop the unneeded column
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

# groupby
dfg = df.groupby(['date', 'retail_item'])['number_of_stores'].sum().unstack()

# sum rows
dfg['Total'] = dfg.sum(axis=1)

# display(dfg.head())
retail_item  GROUND BEEF 70-79%  GROUND BEEF 80-89%  GROUND BEEF 90% OR MORE  Total
date                                                                               
2016-01-01                  940                4020                     1980   6940
2016-01-08                 2000                7770                     3770  13540
2016-01-15                 3000                5640                     6600  15240
2016-01-22                 3060                8830                     1920  13810
2016-01-29                 3060                4420                     2640  10120
```

Comment: right, I found data from public gist so I might have wrong way to parse data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding strings together.  You probably want the number of stores as an integer.  Try this immediately after creating the df, and see if your code starts working.

```
df['number_of_stores'] = df['number_of_stores'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
```